# Execute file as detached process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to execute a file in an indipendent process in node.js.

That's the path to the exe file:
`C:\Users\filip\AppData\Roaming/SoulnetworkLauncher/SNLauncherUpdate.exe`

I alredy tried with child_process.spawn but it doesn't start (no error triggered)

```
const child = cp.spawn("cmd.exe",["C:\Users\filip\AppData\Roaming/SoulnetworkLauncher/SNLauncherUpdate.exe"], {
                        detached: true,
                        stdio: ['ignore']
                    });

child.unref();
```

and with child_process.execFile but it trigger `Error: spawn EBUSY`

```
cp.execFile("C:\Users\filip\AppData\Roaming/SoulnetworkLauncher/SNLauncherUpdate.exe")
```

How should I do?

Comment: Have you tried with the path only using backslashes.

Comment: Just tried, nothing changed